# Password Manager that can sync a Blackberry and Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, sync, passwords, blackberry

I use a Blackberry Bold and a Macbook Pro. I am looking for a solution to have a synchronized password manager between the two devices. All the commercial ones I have discovered won't work between a Blackberry and a Mac.

The almost solution was KeePass. I like the application on the Blackberry but I could not get the sync working reliably to the Mac. As well, I had to run the PC application by using Mono on the Mac and it was pretty slow.

I am happy to pay for a good solution.

Comment: Why didn't KeePass work? I never really tried it on a Blackberry but as far as I know there is one for it, too, and they should use the same data format. Isn't it sufficient to just sync the .kdb file?

Comment: The format is the same but I can't get the sync to work reliably with Missing Sync for Mac. Maybe when the Desktop Manager for Mac comes out from RIM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [lastpass](http://lastpass.com)?

[image]

There's not much to say about it. It syncs [everything](https://lastpass.com/misc_download.php) and stores passwords online. Great product.

Comment: I haven't. But I am now using a Nexus One so it doesn't matter as much. LastPass looks good though.